# Exhibit isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $F = \mathbb Z_5$($\alpha$) where $\alpha^2+2 = 0$, let $F' = \mathbb Z_5(\beta)$ where $\beta^2+\beta+1 = 0$. Exhibit an isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$.

Having trouble getting started with this. Thank you.

Comment: A start: If you decide what $\alpha$ should be mapped to, in terms of $\beta$, or vice-versa, the full mapping will be determined.

Comment: If a polynomial $P(X)$ of degree $ n $ is irreducible over the finite field $ \mathbb{F}_q $, then the quotient $\mathbb{F}_q[X]/(P)$ isomorphic to the finite field $ \mathbb{F}_{q^n} $ by uniqueness of finite fields. Now, your fields $F$ and $F'$ are in this form, so both fields are isomorphic to $ \mathbb{F}_{25} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element of $F$ can be written as $a+b\alpha$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_5$. Let's look for the roots of $x^2+x+1$ in $F$:
\begin{gather}
(a+b\alpha)^2+(a+b\alpha)+1=0
\\
a^2+2ab\alpha+b^2\alpha^2+a+b\alpha+1=0
\\
(a^2+a+2b^2+1)+(2ab+b)\alpha=0
\\
a^2+a+2b^2+1=0,\qquad b(2a+1)=0
\end{gather}
The case $b=0$ can be easily dismissed, so we have $a=-1/2=2$. Thus
$$
4+2+2b^2+1=0
$$
and so $2b^2=-2$ or $b^2=4$.

Then the roots of $x^2+x+1$ in $F$ are $2+2\alpha$ and $2-2\alpha$. We can choose $\beta=2+2\alpha$, so $\alpha=(\beta-2)/2=3\beta-1$.

Consider then the map $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]\to F'$ induced by
$$
x\mapsto 3\beta-1
$$
and check its kernel is $(x^2+2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using your symbols ( except for $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ , which I'm guessing you mean the field with five elements. This is more properly and accurately denoted by $\;\Bbb F_5\;$), we have

$$\begin{align*}&\Bbb F:=\Bbb F_5(\alpha)=\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle\,x^2+2\,\rangle=\left\{\,a\omega+b\;:\;a,b\in\Bbb F_5\;,\;\;\omega^2=-2=3\pmod5\,\right\}\\{}\\
&\Bbb F':=\Bbb F_5(\beta)=\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle\,x^2+x+1\,\rangle=\left\{\,a\xi+b\;:\;a,b\in\Bbb F_5\;,\;\;\xi^2=-\xi-1\,\right\}\end{align*}$$

and in both sets the operations are carried on modulo $\;5\;$ and with the defining relation.

For example, in the first case, we have

$$(\omega+1)(3\omega)=3\omega^2+3\omega=3(-2)+3\omega=-5+3\omega=3\omega-1=3\omega+4$$

and in the second case, for example:

$$(\xi+1)(3\xi)=3\xi^2+3\xi=3(-\xi-1)+3\xi=-3=2$$

Well, you can check directly these indeed are fields (most probably you already know it: the quotien of a commutative unitary ring by a *maximal ideal* is always a field), and now try by yourself to take an educated guess what a nice isomorphism can exist here.

Comment: Yes I mean a field of 5 elements. In my class, we tend to work with $\mathbb Z_n$ fields for some integer $n$. We haven't used the $\mathbb F_5$ notation before. Thank you.